# How to select subset of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a javascript object, say oBj, with a number of attributes, `oBj.att1, oBj.att2 ... oBj.attn`.

I can pass this object into jQuery's param function to quickly create URIs.

Is it possible to select `oBj.att1` and `oBj.att2` and pass that to the param function?

Please excuse me, I'm very inexperienced with Javascript.

Update:

Code sample:

```
var oBj = new Object();
            oBj.att1 = 1;
            oBj.att2 = 2;
            oBj.att3 = 3;
```

Comment: What have you tried and what would you like to achieve? A code sample would be useful

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes to work it up. I'll update...

Comment: Also jQuery you used

Comment: Tomasz, the jQuery was simply $.param(oBj);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Sure.

The easiest way I find is using a 3rd party library called 'lodash' (or 'underscore'). After including the library you can:

```
_.pick(oBj, ['attr1', 'attr2'])
```

See: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#pick

But if you don't want to use a 3rd party library, then you can:

```js
var oBj = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
};

var pick = function (obj, attrs) {
    return attrs.reduce(function (result, key) {
        result[key] = obj[key];
        return result;
    }, {});
};

console.log(pick(oBj, ['a', 'c']));
```

Comment: suggesting a whole library or a pick function to access 2 Javascript properties looks a big overkill.. at least you updated so it wasn't a library only answer..

Comment: That's great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
// lets say you have  function

    function process_data(data )
    {
        // logic goes here 
    }

// this may be you json object
    var json_data  = {
        "obj1": {....} ,
        "obj2": {....} ,
        "obj3": {....} ,
        .
        .
        .
        "obj1": {....} ,
    }

//create new object with required attributes

    var new_obj = {}
    new_obj["obj1"] = json_data["obj1"]
    new_obj["obj2"] = json_data["obj2"]

// pass to function

    process_data(new_obj)
```